# Android SQlite 3 execute commands

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an automation on android platform and got stuck at the db part of the app.
I need to clear all the data from a table "tablename" through adb commands. I have got the following commands that do the job manually but I cannot automate it.

adb shell sqlite /data/data/.../databases/log.db
delete * from tablename

When I create a batch file for this the 
sqlite> 
had opened but the delete command was not executed. How can I achieve this?

batch file data:

adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/.../databases/activitylog.db
delete * from events;

Comment: Show the batch file. And why can't you do this directly in your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL command to execute must be a single parameter, so you have to quote it:

```
adb shell sqlite3 .../activitylog.db 'delete from events'
```

<sup>And I took the liberty of correcting the SQL syntax.</sup>

Comment: thanks! had done a lot of hard work from morning.Finally got it working

Answer (score 0):

Your Device needs to be rooted for this.

Way one:
Run your sqlite3 command after "su". 
I prefer the following way:

```
    adb shell
    su
    cd <toYourDbDir>
    sqlite3 /data/data/com.symantec.mobilesecurity/databases/activitylog.db delete * from events
```

If you have to do this again, just use the up-arrow to get the last command and execute it with enter.

Way two:
Install [sqlite Database Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mixo.sqlitedbeditor), open the Db and edit what you want.

Comment: The question asks how to do this in a batch file.